# HELP to solve - PDE First order

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have this equation $$ u_x+uu_y=0$$ by the book "Handbook of First order Partial Differential Equations - page 290." The general solution is $F(ux-y,u)$, where $F$ is a arbitrary function.

I try check this answer but I'm confuse. I start with this; the characteristic system is

$$\dfrac{dx}{1}=\dfrac{dy}{u}=\dfrac{u}{"0"},$$ so

$$\dfrac{du}{"0"}  \rightarrow u=C_1$$ where $C_1$ is constant. And $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=u \rightarrow ux-y = C_2$$ where $C_2$ is constant. Therefore $$C_1=F(C_2)\rightarrow F(ux-y)$$

I dont see how I have $F(C_1, C3)$ for exemple, how can I get $C_3$?

Comment: $$
\dfrac{dx}{dr} = 1,\,\, \dfrac{dy}{dr} = u,\,\,\dfrac{du}{dr} =0
$$
I am not sure why it is usually denoted as $dr= \text{blah} =\text{blah}$ all the time. Then you can carry on as usual without that naughty divide by zero.

Comment: Right, but this parametric curve "r" still not work for me. for exemple.

$$\dfrac{dx}{dr} = 1 \rightarrow x= r + C_2,$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dr} = u \rightarrow y= ur + C_1,$$
$$\dfrac{du}{dr} = 0 \rightarrow u= C_3,$$

So $C_3= F(C_1,C_2) = F(ur-y,x-r)$. I'm sorry, but i'm still confuse how can I get "x-r=y" or x=r its clearly if C2=0

Answer (score 1):

$$ u_x+uu_y=0$$

The first part is correct :

The characteristic system is

$$\dfrac{dx}{1}=\dfrac{dy}{u}=\dfrac{u}{"0"},$$ so

$$\dfrac{du}{"0"}  \rightarrow u=C_1$$ where $C_1$ is constant. And $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=u \rightarrow ux-y = C_2$$ where $C_2$ is constant.

At this point we already have 2 characteristics equations. There is no need for more : The implicit form is $F(C_1\, , \, C_2)$

Thus, the general solution expressed on implicit form is :
$$F(u\, , \, ux-y)=0$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

This result can de presented on various equivalent implicit forms. For example :
$$u=f(xu-y)$$
where $f$ is any differentiable function.

or $\quad u=\frac{1}{x}\left( y+g(u)\right) \quad$ where $g$ is any differentiable function.

But is is not possible to separate $u$  without loss of generality, in order to express $u(x,y)$ on explicit form.